# Laravel - Saving a .txt File to mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have been struggling to create something that can save txt files into a mySQL database. I have managed to create something that saves JSON files but not txt files.

Here is the txt file in question: https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/sbas.txt. This txt file contains a few satellites with their data. Each satellite has exactly three lines, no exceptions. So, for example here is one satellite:

```
AOR-E (EGNOS/PRN 120)   
1 24307U 96053A   17257.68868765 -.00000150  00000-0  00000-0 0  9992
2 24307   2.8040  77.2609 0004175 104.1816  44.8421  1.00271450 76939
```

The first lines tells us the satellite name. The next two lines give us some parameters, which always start with the numbers `1` and `2`. This format will not change - the name on line `0` and the two lines after it, which start in `1` or `2`.

What I want to be able to do is to create a row for each satellite - with the columns `object_name` for line `0`, `tle_line1` for line `1` and `tle_line2` for line `2`.

I have managed to create something that saves data from a JSON format into the SQL database. Maybe some can be deviated from that?

I am using Laravel and Guzzle for the HTTP requests:

```
$api = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://celestrak.org',
]); 
$response = $api->get('jsonlocater');
$data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    foreach ($data as $attributes) {
    $attributes = array_change_key_case($attributes, CASE_LOWER);
    Satellites::create($attributes);
}
```

Comment: You could save each line to a DB, then, on request, combine those lines and create the txt file for download? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Ice76 - I just want to save the data contained in the txt file in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not sure what is your response format but using vanilla `PHP` you may do something like the following to fetch the contents in array:

```
$url = 'http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/sbas.txt';
$lines = file($url, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$arrays = array_map(function($array) {
    $columns = ['object_name', 'tle_line1', 'tle_line2'];
    return array_combine($columns, array_map('trim', $array));
}, array_chunk($lines, 3));
```

Now, if you `dd($arrays)` the result then you'll get something like the following:

[image]

From this result, you should be easily able to create entries in your database. Each array in image should be an entry/row in your database table. For example:

```
\DB::table('table_name')->insert($arrays);
```

Note that, if you've timestamps (created_at & updated_at) in your table then you've to add those fields in each array when generating the arrays.

Comment: 20;ABB200B        ;ABB200B                       ;Boombox CD/Radio/MP3/USB;

if file data is something like that not spaces but semi colon seperated?